# Can you change the android id and onClick tag dynamically that was originally set in xml?

Tags: android, audio

Is it possible to change the id and onClick tag dynamically?

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/actionAudio"
        android:text="{faw-microphone}"
        android:layout_weight = "2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:onClick="onRecordAudio" />
```

For example,  I'm trying to record an audio clicking a single button with id and onClick tag. That button will serve as the stop button also. To be able to do that, I'm thinking of dynamically changing those tags to manipulate it visually and also the **onclick** event.

Is this approach okay or are there better ways to do such thing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you use toogle button instead of button, and you can check isChecked() in its onClick() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your scenario as I have implemented the Recording sound and playing Audio functionality just two days ago, However my answer is not a solution to your question, but it is a better and clean approach compared to yours,

1. Create two different buttons in xml, one for record and one for stop.
2. Specify different methods for onClick to both of them.
3. Hide one of the button and display the other one according to the user click events in code(i.e change the visibility accordingly).

This way your logic is completely decoupled and separated, and you dont have to switch between button images, click event checks etc.

- When user presses **Record**, its registered onClick method will be called, hide the clicked button in the method by `setVisibility(View.GONE)` and make the **Stop** button visible again by `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and vice versa

Toggle Button can also get things done for you, but later when you will decide to add new buttons like playing, pausing sound, the above approach will work out well for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip :) This is what I decided to use.

Comment: Most welcome, you know what, using this approach, you can add other buttons (if you want to ) later on without breaking the Code, like **Play** for playing the sound, **Pause** for pausing the sound. Each button will have its own method and no dependency issues will happen. Good Luck...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways but the simple solution is for you use Toggle Button instead of normal Button.

```
<ToggleButton  
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"  
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"  
    android:text="ToggleButton1"  
    android:textOn="Record"  
    android:textOff="Stop" />
```

and..

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        // The toggle is enabled
    } else {
        // The toggle is disabled
    }
}
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about ToggleButton until now. I would definitely use it for other use-case. I went on with the setting visibility method. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Id` of the any `View` using this method

```
yourView.setId(int);
```

and set on click listener like this

```
View v = findViewById(id);
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // Perform action on click
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button button;
    boolean f=true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// code
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                if(f) {
                    button.setText("Stop");
                    f=false;
                    // your code
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Stroped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    button.setText("Activate");
                    f=true;
                }
        }
    }
```

The easiest way to do this using the if/else 
and you dont need to reset id

don't forget to implement View.OnClickListner

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do that

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            if (((String) v.getTag()) != null && ((String) v.getTag()).equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")) {
                v.setTag("START");
                // start
                 // you can also use boolean like v.setTag(true)
            } else {
                v.setTag("STOP");
                // stop
            }
        }
    });
```